# What is a good alternative to Axure RP in linux?

Tags: wine, design, web-design

I have been using Pencil on Windows for several months, but I had to change to Axure RP because in Pencil there are no master templates.

While Pencil is okay for small projects, changing the header on bigger projects requires changing it page by page(bye, bye...time).

I tested justinmind in WINE, but it isn't stable. It would hang often, and there were many errors.

Are there any good alternatives? (Not web-based if possible)

Comment: If you want to run an application in Wine, I recommend you follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to install the latest version, as there have been many fixes and improvements since version 1.6 (the version in the Ubuntu repos).

Answer (score -1):

You can try Apache OpenOffice Draw

[image]

Or several other ones that do similar things. Poke around [find one that fits you](http://alternativeto.net/software/axure-rp-pro/)

Comment: Openoffice is not recommended for most users as it is not being developed near as fast as Libreoffice.

Comment: Thats why i provided the link ;)

Comment: Still, it would be better to replace the OpenOffice Draw recommendation with Libreoffice Draw and maybe include an installation command including the Libreoffice PPA (`ppa:libreoffice/ppa`) to get the latest version.

Comment: Besides, Libreoffice isn't even listed in the link.